# Jquery DOM setting checked in checkbox works for true not false

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am trying to set the checked value of a checkbox to incoming data from Mongo.  It works fine if the value is true, but when the value is false, it still checks the box.  Can anyone tell me what is wrong.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chk" name="interested" value="{{inmate.interested}}" onclick="chkSet(this)">Not Interested <br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="chk" name="correspondence" value="{{inmate.correspondence}}" onclick="chkSet(this)">Req Correspondence<br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="chk" name="study" value="{{inmate.study}}" onclick="chkSet(this)">Request Study<br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="chk" name="specialtyItemsApproved" value="{{inmate.specialtyItemsApproved}}" onclick="chkSet(this)">Specialty Items
Approved<br/>
<br>

$(document).ready(function(){

    document.getElementsByName("interested")[0].checked=document.getElementsByName("interested")[0].value;
    document.getElementsByName("correspondence")[0].checked=document.getElementsByName("correspondence")[0].value;
    document.getElementsByName("study")[0].checked=document.getElementsByName("study")[0].value;
    document.getElementsByName("specialtyItemsApproved")[0].checked=document.getElementsByName("specialtyItemsApproved")[0].value;

});
```

Comment: The only jQuery I see in that question is the `ready` call. Any particular reason you're not using it for the other things?

Comment: What are you doing with `chkSet(this)` function ?

Comment: `if("false") alert("hi");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`document.getElementsByName("interested")[0].checked=document.getElementsByName("interested")[0].value;` sets the `checked` property based on the value of the element, which is always a string. So it will coerce the string to a boolean. All non-blank strings are *truthy*, so both `"true"` and `"false"` will set `checked` to `true`.

If you use an `==` test, you can set the `checked` accordingly:

```
document.getElementsByName("interested")[0].checked =
    document.getElementsByName("interested")[0].value == "true";
```

---

That said, the purpose of the value of a checkbox in HTML/DOM is **not** to indicate whether it's checked, so setting `value` to `"true"` or `"false"` in the first place is probably not what you really want to do. The purpose of `value` is to say what value should be sent with the form **if** the checkbox is checked. Example:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="roomoptions" value="non-smoking">
<input type="checkbox" name="roomoptions" value="with-kitchen">
<input type="checkbox" name="roomoptions" value="en-suite">
```

The form will have `roomoptions=non-smoking` if that checkbox is checked, and/or `roomoptions=with-kitchen` if *that* checkbox is checked, and/or `roomoptions=en-suite` if *that* checkbox is checked. If none of them is checked, the form won't have any `roomoptions` sent at all. All three are sent if all three checkboxes are checked.

Separately, you cannot use the same `id` on more than one element in an HTML/DOM document. `id`s must be **unique**. So you can't use `id="chk"` on all of your checkboxes.

So I suspect you really want something more like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chk-interested" name="interested" {{#if inmate.interested}}checked{{/if}} onclick="chkSet(this)">Not Interested <br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="chk-correspondence" name="correspondence" {{#if inmate.correspondence}}checked{{/if}}" onclick="chkSet(this)">Req Correspondence<br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="chk-study" name="study" {{#if inmate.study}}checked{{/if}} onclick="chkSet(this)">Request Study<br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="chk-specialty-items-approved" name="specialtyItemsApproved" {{#if inmate.specialtyItemsApproved}}checked{{/if}} onclick="chkSet(this)">Specialty Items
```

Then you don't need your JavaScript at all.

I didn't put a value on those, which means that when the form is sent in (if you're sending in the form), the value for `interested` and such that the server will receive will be the default value `"on"`. E.g., the form will either not have an `interested` field at all (the checkbox wasn't checked), or it will have `interested=on`.

Note that unless you use those `id`s for something, you can just leave them off; it's the `name` that the form will use when submitted. But I made them unique to demonstrate that you must do that.

Comment: Thanks that worked it was the fact that the True and False were string not boolean.